# Bootable USB on Windows 7, 32-bit

Tags: usb-installation

Currently I am using **Windows 7, 32- Bit.**
I downloaded "*ubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64*"
Please tell me how to create Bootable USB to install Ubuntu Linux on Windows 7, 32- Bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use software that allows this. My favorite is [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), but I believe [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is far more preferred option.

Also, you downloaded 64-bit version of Ubuntu (17.10 is not distributed in 32-bit desktop version), so you should probably download older Ubuntu, that still supports 32-bit architecture on desktop ([16.04 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) offered on official website should be fine), because your Windows version suggests your processor does not support 64-bit architecture.

Comment: _“your Windows version suggests your processor does not support 64-bit architecture”_ Yes, it suggests but it is not necessarily the case. Instead of recommending an _older_ Ubuntu version (but still supported LTS is fine), I’d recommend a flavor that is still distributed as a 32-bit version – like Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: If I download Ubuntu from below link, Then it will 32-bit or 64-bit?- "https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute?version=16.04.4&architecture=amd64"

Comment: The link you provided is for 64-bit architecture, but that page is interactive, when you visited it, it automatically detected your architecture and changed link accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 prominent non-geeky way ( in my knowledge ). Please search Google for all these programs.

1. Unetbootin
2. Rufus &
3. Linux Live USB Installer

All 3 programs are very easy to use, completely GUI based and best for beginners.

Enjoy!